# SetDate on jquery Datepicker onClose does not change value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

i have a table and each row has a datepicker. Datepickers are only selecting months and on close i set the first day of the month except if this day is before the minDate so i want to set minDate there.

SetDate function does not work. My log gives me that properDate is set correctly but when i pass it in the setDate the result does not change and somehow it is stack to first Day of the month. What am i missing?

```
    function initDatepickerSchedule(){  

        $(".datepickerSchedule").each(function(){

            $(this).datepicker({
                showOn: "both",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                minDate: scheduleTaskMinDate(),
                maxDate: scheduleTaskMaxDate($(this).closest("tr").find(".ScheduledTaskQtyInput").val(),$(this).closest("tr").find(".ScheduledTaskCompletedQtyInput").val()),
                showButtonPanel: true,  
                onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                    function isDonePressed(){
                       return $('#ui-datepicker-div').html().indexOf('ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all ui-state-hover') > -1;
                    }

                    if (isDonePressed()){
                        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                        var properDate=new Date(year, month, 1);
                        var minDate=$(this).datepicker("option","minDate");                  
                        console.log(properDate);// 2019-12-1
                        console.log(minDate);//2019-12-2
                        console.log(properDate<minDate);// true
                        if(properDate<minDate){
                            properDate=minDate;
                        }
                        console.log("before set");
                        console.log(properDate===minDate);//true
                        console.log(properDate);//2019-12-2

                        $(this).datepicker("setDate",properDate);
                        console.log($(this).datepicker("getDate"));//2019-12-1
                        var coNo=$(this).closest("tr").find(".changeOrderNoInput").val();
                        $(this).closest("tr").find(".ScheduledTaskVersion").val(studyTaskScheduleVersion($(this).datepicker("getDate"),coNo));
                        $("#SubmitScheduleDistButton").prop('disabled', true).prop('title',"Validate without Errors to Unlock");
                    }
                }               
            }).focus(function(){
                $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
                $(this).attr("autocomplete","off");
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that max Date was really relevant. In this specific case i should have a date inside the same month for the maxDate, but for some reason (i do not remember and checked possible influence in other parts of the program but i can not find any problem)i was returning the first date of the month.

So this was not shown on the datepicker case calendar was hidden so i could not know.
And this is way it was overriding the set function cause of the maxDate.